# exporting AD users displayName for selected groups only - powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, filter, import, export

I am new to powershell so please excuse me if the answer is quite simple. I am trying to get user list sorted by selected AD groups and export that to table or csv at least. Due to the fact that:

```bsh
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "TestGroupName"
```

... gives me only user IDs for my AD, I used below:

```bsh
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "TestGroupName" | Get-ADObject -Properties displayName
```

This works perfectly but I do not want to type manually each group there so I decided to first export groups that I need which are beginning with "Test":

```bsh
Get-ADGroup -Filter "name -like 'Test*'" |Select-Object Name | Export-csv -path \Groups.csv
```

Now I want to use information from Groups.csv to list all user displayName for groups listed in Groups.csv so I tried something like that:

```bsh
Import-Csv -Path .\Groups.csv | Get-ADGroupMember ForEach($Name in $Groups) | Get-ADObject -Properties displayName | Export-csv -path \UsersByGroups.csv
```

unfortunately it does not work properly maybe because I still do not get exactly how to use **ForEach**

Can someone with more experience have a look and help?

Thanks!
Maciej

Answer (score 1):

Just pipe the groups output by `Get-ADGroup -Filter ...` directly to `Get-ADGroupMember`:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter "name -like 'Test*'" |Get-ADGroupMember |Get-ADObject -Properties displayName
```

Comment: Thank you this works well but not fully as I expected. Now I do as below and it gives me a list of users sorted by ADgroup but names of the groups are not listed in csv file..

**Get-ADGroup -Filter "name -like 'TEST*'" | Get-ADGroupMember | Get-ADObject -Properties displayName | sort ADgroup | Export-csv -path \UsersByGroups.csv**

Can this be done somehow?

Comment: I meant I do get list of user full names sorted by groups but groups are not listed so I need to guess where each group begins in the csv